# Searchkick eagerload acts_as_taggable (deeply nested model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, acts-as-taggable-on, searchkick, acts-as-taggable

I'm trying to make Searchkick eager load tags created by the acts_as_taggable gem, hover it seems to ignore it so i think i'm doin it wrong this is my `search_import`:

```
searchkick language: "norwegian"
scope :search_import, -> { includes([:venue, :artists, :taggings, :tags ]) }
```

I have also tried:

```
searchkick language: "norwegian"
scope :search_import, -> { includes([:venue, :artists, taggings: { :tags } ]) }
```

But then everything crashes...

Does any one know how to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried this? 
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects

Comment: Try with `array` instead of `hash` for `taggings: [ :tags ]`, as: `scope :search_import, -> { includes([:venue, :artists, taggings: [ :tags ] ]) }`.  Also, when you say everything crashes, please post the relevant stacktrace so the problem could be understood better.

Comment: `tagings: [:tags]` seems to crash aswell. I'll try to update with stack trace soon. I tried this however `scope :search_import, -> { includes([:venue, :artists, taggings: [ :tag ] ]) }` does not seem to make any difference.